# Google Analytics won't track a view on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I've added the newest Google Analytics SDK to my iOS application (version 2.0 beta 4).
I did the same as the guide says and added this code to app delegate:

```
// Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
// Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
// Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
[GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
// Create tracker instance.
self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-TRACKINGID-2"];//UA-33873963-13 - My testing google analytics trackingId

[self.tracker setSessionStart:YES];
[self.tracker setSessionTimeout:60];
```

Now, on each view I've added this:

```
self.trackedViewName = @"Main Menu Screen";
```

Everything works fine, but for some reason 3 out of the 20 screens is not sending themselves to Google and I don't have a clue why. I've searched all over the net, but no one has came across this issue. I figured that if someone familiar with this issue, it's on stack-overflow.

Please help me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has been fixed with the simplest way.

The code that I wrote up, is for the `AppDelegate`. After the tracker has been initialized once with tracking ID, you just need to call it in each view that you are using it. (I'm not sure about that but anyway it worked for me.)

So, in the **`AppDelegate`**:

```
// Optional: automatically send uncaught exceptions to Google Analytics.
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
// Optional: set Google Analytics dispatch interval to e.g. 20 seconds.
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
// Optional: set debug to YES for extra debugging information.
[GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
// Create tracker instance.
self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-TRACKINGID-2"];//UA-33873963-13 - My testing google analytics trackingId

[self.tracker setSessionStart:YES];
[self.tracker setSessionTimeout:60];
```

Inside the view controllers **`viewDidLoad`**:

```
[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
[self.tracker sendView:@"Some name"];
```

After doing this, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Notice that they updated their sdk. In version 3 it won't work. Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289581/gaitrackedviewcontroller-and-uitableviewcontroller.

Comment: Yeah, but I published this answer 7 months ago.

Comment: Yes I know, I wrote the comment for everyone who will try your solution with sdk 3.

Comment: Cool. yeah, the new SDK is way better.. :)

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem some time ago. I bet that you don't call the following methods in your overrides:

1. `[super viewDidLoad]` in your `-(void)viewDidLoad` override
2. `[super viewDidAppear:animated]` in your `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` override
3. `[super viewDidUnload]` in your `-(void)viewDidUnload` override
4. ... (take care of all the other methods that you are overriding from `GAITrackedViewController`

Concretely, your methods should look like the following:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  // call this at the beginning of the overridden methods
  self.screenName = @"Some Name"; 
  [super viewDidLoad];

  // your remaining code here
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

  // your remaining code here
}
```

The most important methods are `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear:` since especially for real time tracking the `viewDidAppear:` shows that this view is currently visible.

**EDIT:** Since version 3.0 of the Google Analytics SDK the screenName property should be set before calling the `viewDidLoad` method of super.

Comment: I fixed the problem just by doing `[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];` and than call for `[self.tracker sendView:@"Some name"];`. After doing this, it worked perfectly.

Comment: @who9vy Thanks man! Such an obvious thing when you think about it, but really easy to miss. 
Google should really put this in their docs.

Comment: Thanks - that was the ticket. Just writing a script now to find any view(did|will) scripts without a super call.. Doh!

Answer (score 15):

I am using version 3.02 and encountered the same problem.  The following fixed my problem:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   self.screenName = @"My Screen"; // set screenName prior to calling super
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];

   ...
}
```

You definitely want to to call `super` because it triggers sending the ga data. It appears to me that the `screenName` needs to be set prior to it.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me after trying 10 other methods from around here. I'm on GAI 3.0 I believe.

Comment: Debugging GA automatic view tracking is so frustrating! This worked for me too (GAI v3.0.6 on iOS 7).
Terrible & misleading documentation can drive you mad.

Answer (score 2):

So, I found the answer to this issue:

In header add this: `#import "GAI.h"`

Now in viewDidLoad:

1. Add `self.trackedViewName = @"Some Name";`
2. Than do this:
   `[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];`
3. Also add this:
   `[self.tracker sendView:@"Some Name"];`

Than it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

So.. This is for the noobies out there.. (myself included)..

This might be a dumb thing to think of, but for me was putting the stupid **super view did appear [super viewDidAppear:animated];** after you call to set the screen name.

As an aside, I'm just an iOS user, but when I looked into the gaitrackedviewcontroller.h the latest screen name to set is, well, screenname not trackedviewname. So, this is what mine looked like:

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

  self.screenName = @"Login Screen";

  [super viewDidAppear:animated];

}

Good Luck. Hope this helps anyone. Stay Classy.

Answer (score 0):

In **3.10** environment, I had similar problem. I have tried other guy way, but no hope. Finally, I found the ANSWER is at the outside of official instructions.

After adding two lines, it works.

```
 NSDictionary *appDefaults = @{kAllowTracking: @(YES)};
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
```

Official instructions doesn't mention we need register kAllowTraking in defaults.