# GAITrackedViewController and UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics

With Google Analytics for iOS v2 Google suggests subclassing their `GAITrackedViewController` class in place of `UIViewController`. What do we do in the case of UITableViewController?

[source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/#screen-tracking)

```
#import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

@interface AboutViewController : GAITrackedViewController
```

Answer (score 126, accepted):

## Manual Screen Tracking

Remember that extending GAITrackedViewController is only one way to track screen views. The manual way is just as easy.

#### SDK v2

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
    // returns the same tracker you created in your app delegate
    // defaultTracker originally declared in AppDelegate.m
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    // manual screen tracking
    [tracker sendView:@"Home Screen"];
}
```

#### SDK v3

```
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
```

...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    
    // returns the same tracker you created in your app delegate
    // defaultTracker originally declared in AppDelegate.m
    id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    // This screen name value will remain set on the tracker and sent with
    // hits until it is set to a new value or to nil.
    [tracker set:kGAIScreenName
           value:@"Home Screen"];

    // manual screen tracking
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] build]];
}
```

#### Reference

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/screens#manual
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/screens#manual

Comment: I had to use trackerWithTrackingId: but that worked. Thank you for the lead.

Comment: nevermind. [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker] did work. thanks again.

Comment: I found this very confusing myself, but defaultTracker just works like magic. Glad I could help.

Comment: @dmzza i tried your code, but I can't make it work. can you explain further how to implement it. thanks in advance:)

Comment: You can put these two lines anywhere in your code to track a screen view. id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker]; [tracker sendView:@"Home Screen"];

Comment: Make sure you include this line in your .h file: #import "GAITrackedViewController.h"

Comment: Why you call sendView in  `viewWillAppear`?  will it better to send in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: I had to #import "GAIFields.h" to make kGAIScreenName available

Comment: Its better to do it in `viewDidAppear`, documentation in `GAITrackedViewController.h` says so.

Comment: It will work in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. But I changed my answer to align with the way `GAITrackedViewController` does it as you pointed out. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @rohan-patel Be specific. What doesn't work for you? Do you get an error?

Comment: Just to add: If you are using an older v3 that isn't the latest, the last line should instead be: `[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];`

Comment: regarding this comment: `This screen name value will remain set on the tracker and sent with hits until it is set to a new value or to nil.` does this mean this value will need to be set to `nil` on `viewWillDisapear`?

Comment: @Julian You could set it to `nil`, but wouldn't you give it a new value for every view anyway? Is there ever a case that you would want to send a `screenView` without a `screenName`? Leaving it set shouldn't cause memory leaks because the `tracker` is a singleton.

Comment: after further inspection, it seems like the view will remain as 'active' for 30 mins even if the user minimizes the app, or leaves the view. which may be misleading.

Comment: @dmzza - you have a point, that was the intended implementation on my end anyway, just didn't get that far. was looking to see how accurate and meaningful the measurements are... but i agree :)

Answer (score 14):

In an effort to clean up the manual tracking code in my Swift project, I created the following  `UIViewController` extension.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func trackScreenView(screenName: String) {
        let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
        tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: screenName)
        tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createAppView().build())
    }
}
```

It's probably not proper to use an extension this way, as I'm not using any properties from the UIViewController, but it's a convenient way that feels better than a global method.  If you don't mind using your class name instead of a nicely formatted name, you could even use the `NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType)` to get the ViewController class name like so:

```
extension UIViewController {
    func trackScreenView() {
        let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
        tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: NSStringFromClass(self.dynamicType))
        tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createAppView().build())
    }
}
```

This allows me to add manual tracking from my UITableViewControllers with just the following code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    trackScreenView("Detail View")  //Or call this without any arguments if using the NSStringFromClass idea 
}
```

Nice and clean.  Enjoy!

Comment: Very nice, very easilly implemented aswell, thank you.

Comment: "It's probably not proper to use an extension this way"... No, this is actually a perfectly proper use of an extension. In fact it really puzzles me that Google didn't do this themselves. Making all your view controllers a subclass of GAITrackedViewController just to do analytics tracking, thats what is improper. What if you wanted to use some other framework that also required subclassing their custom View Controller class? No, extension is the way to go. Great answer!

Comment: "In fact it really puzzles me that Google didn't do this themselves" and then "What if you wanted to use some other framework"... So if 2 services created a category that had "trackScreenView" method the build would most likely fail and if they were different then you would need to call 2 methods in every viewDidAppear. There is no victory in this solution. The answer for this kind of things is to ALWAYS have a custom superclass for the view controllers. Override the view did appear on the superclass and call whatever calls you need from there.

Answer (score 4):

As a result of the Sdk missing a GAITrackedTableViewController I created a simple neat implementation of the manual screen viev tracking.

Create a category for the GAI class, as this is already singleton and easy accessible.

```
#import "GAI+Tracking.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"

@implementation GAI (Tracking)

- (void)trackScreenView:(NSString *)screenName
{
    [self.defaultTracker set:kGAIScreenName value:screenName];
    [self.defaultTracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
}

@end
```

Now just track a screen view like this

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[GAI sharedInstance] trackScreenView:@"Counts map screen"];
}
```

This kind of overules Googles idea of having more than one tracking at the same time. (I haven't had the need yet). To acommodate this just rename your tracking method after which tracker it uses, and use what ever tracker you want.

```
#import "GAI+Tracking.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"

@implementation GAI (Tracking)

- (void)trackDefaultScreenView:(NSString *)screenName
{
    [self.defaultTracker set:kGAIScreenName value:screenName];
    [self.defaultTracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];
}

@end
```

Comment: This is a clean implementation of it, saving everyone from copy/pasting it everywhere for UITableViewControllers. Cheers mate.

Comment: Just a note - createAppView is deprecated. Use createScreenView instead.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all your viewDidAppear call [super viewDidAppear]

Then make sure every single one of your subclass of UITableViewController is also a subclass of myTableViewController

in [myTableViewController viewDidAppear], implement all those other answers.

Just complementing all the other good answers out there. That way you get something as good as GAITrackedViewController.h

The same way I make sure all of my other UIViewController subclass is also a subclass of super UIViewController and then I do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift you can use

```
AppDelegate.appDelegateIns.defTrackerIns?.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "Enter Your Screen Name")
        AppDelegate.appDelegateIns.defTrackerIns?.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

Include This in your App Delegate

```
static let appDelegateIns = AppDelegate()
    let gai = GAI.sharedInstance()
    let defTrackerIns = GAI.sharedInstance().tracker(withTrackingId: "Your Tracking Id")
    let gaDefTargetURL = "https://developers.google.com/analytics"
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming they don't have a subclass of UITableViewController themselves, I don't see why you couldn't use their GAITrackedViewController, and then implement the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate protocols yourself.

Comment: This leaves me with two errors. Commenting the following lines removes the errors but then `UITableViewController` doesn't load any rows. :(

1)`No visible @interface for 'GAITrackedViewController' declares the selector 'initWithStyle:'`

2)`Property 'clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear' not found on object of type 'MenuViewController *'`

Comment: That's because those are properties on UITableViewController, not UIViewController. Instead of calling 'initWithStyle:' on the viewcontroller, you'd have to have the viewcontroller set the style on the UITableView instance it owns. Same thing with the clearsSelection property.

Comment: If you have to change your entire architcture because if a simple tracking framework, something is really wrong. I don't see why Google didn't make an override for ITableViewController. Maybe it's because manual tracking is so simple. I say: Don't bother with Googles override. Doing it manually also gives you more control.

Comment: UITableViewController does a ton more than implementing the UITableViewDatasource. It also handles scrolling the tableview if you set an inputfield as first responder inside a cell. You loose this and much more when not inheriting from UITableViewController.

Answer (score -1):

From https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

UITableViewController  Inherits from    UIViewController : UIResponder : NSObject

On can subclass GAITrackedViewController and not do anything extra for virtually any kind of ViewController that inherits fro UIViewController.