# Multiple Inheritance in Objective-C (UIRefreshControl Usage)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I decided to use `UIRefreshControl` in one of my `UIViewController` instance to support pull to refresh functionality. Since it is only applicable to `UITableViewControllers`, I converted my controller into a "`UITableViewController` subclass". However, I am currently making use of Google "Analytics SDK" in my project to track page, views sessions so on and so forth, thus all of my controller classes are already "subclassed" with **`GAITrackedViewController`** like below.

[image: Screenshot from Google SDK's offical documentation]

How can I use `UIRefreshControl` without losing the abilities of Google "Analytics SDK" in my view controller?

Comment: TableView Controller is not necessary. You can still add refreshconrol to tableview.

Comment: you can add refresh controller in tableview or any similar control, like this [self.calendarTableView addSubview:refreshControl];

Comment: But, this behaviour is not supported by Apple and when you do that, you give away all the internal things [tableViewController setRefreshControl:] does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAITrackedViewController is only one of the ways add the tracking inside your iOS app.

There are other Manual Screen Measurement tracking, please visit:-

1. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/screens#manual
2. [GAITrackedViewController and UITableViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289581/gaitrackedviewcontroller-and-uitableviewcontroller)

So, if you want to use `UITableViewControllers`, you can still use that.

Comment: Thanks. It seems, the best way of both using refresh control and handling screen tracking is to do the screen tracking manually.