# Google Analytics for iOS - manual screen tracking won't work

Tags: ios, swift, analytics

I've got a problem with screen tracking on iOS. I'm doing it like it's presented in sample app from Google:

```
    let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().defaultTracker
    tracker.set("My screen", value: "Value")
    tracker.send(GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView().build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
```

And it doesn't work. It's correctly tracking events though, and when I'm subclassing View Controller as GAITrackedViewController it's tracking screens. But, I don't want to subclass my view controllers just to track screens. Does anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to inherit your ViewControllers, just do this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let googleTracker = GAI.sharedInstance().trackerWithTrackingId("UA-YOUR_TRACKER_ID")
    googleTracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: "MyPageName")
    let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()
    googleTracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
}
```

Of course you do not need to create the "googleTracker" object every time, do it on some central place and get it from there.

Comment: Still not working. When I'm subclassing VC as GAITrackedViewController, it shows instantaneously.

Comment: Are you using my code with the constant kGAIScreenName?

Comment: And have you replaced UA-YOUR_TRACKER_ID with _your_ actual tracker id?

Comment: If I didn't replace your constant, it wouldn't compile. And, I don't need to set tracker ID, it has been taken from generated .plist from Google Analytics webpage. It works without setting track id, because event tracking and screen tracking from subclassing VC works too.

Comment: I do it all the time in this way without problems. See also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289581/gaitrackedviewcontroller-and-uitableviewcontroller

Comment: Okay, it works! Maybe there was some delay involved.

Comment: @luigi3 for future reference the `kGAIScreenName ` constant is not one set by @darko, it is one defined right there in the method to send to Google Analytics for you to track it. As long as there is a string there, it will compile.

Comment: @luigi3 Also - how much delay before yours finally worked (from start to finish)? There are a lot of "app analytics take a while to register" comments on here (and similar threads). It would be nice to have a some sort of number...minutes, hours, whatever. Thanks.

Comment: @ClaytonAndrewCohn hey, I guess it was like one day.